# Trouble doing a custom DialogPreference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences

I'm currently learning a ton about android apps and I don't know much about custom preference items
So I tried looking arround on internet and then made my code :

```
package com.corrupted.radheat.TEMPER

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.TypedArray
import android.support.v7.preference.DialogPreference
import android.support.v7.preference.Preference
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View
import android.widget.NumberPicker


class NumericPreference @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.dialogPreferenceStyle, defStyleRes: Int = defStyleAttr) : DialogPreference(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes){

private var mWidget: NumberPicker? = null

private var value = DEFAULT_VALUE

init {

    dialogLayoutResource = R.layout.bumberpref_pickertest
}

protected fun onBindDialogView(view: View) {
    mWidget = view.findViewById(R.id.picker) as NumberPicker
    mWidget!!.minValue = 0
    mWidget!!.maxValue = 10
    mWidget!!.value = value
}

override fun onGetDefaultValue(a: TypedArray, index: Int): Any {
    return a.getInteger(index, DEFAULT_VALUE)
}

override fun onSetInitialValue(restorePersistedValue: Boolean, defaultValue: Any) {
    if (restorePersistedValue) {
        value = getPersistedInt(DEFAULT_VALUE)
    } else {
        value = defaultValue as Int
        persistInt(value)
    }
}

fun onDialogClosed(positiveResult: Boolean) {
    if (positiveResult) {
        value = mWidget!!.value
        persistInt(value)
    }
}

companion object {
    private const val DEFAULT_VALUE = 0
}

}
```

But , my custom items doesnt works without the onDisplayPreferenceDialog function which one i have no idea how to write so I copy/pasted an already working java function but there is a lot of derecated stuff (the most recent tutorials are from 3 years ago) and some function were deprecated on the last api

so can someone help me with updating this function

```
    fun onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference: Preference) {
    if (preference is NumericPreference) {
        val dialogFragment = DialogPrefFragCompat.newInstance(preference.key)
        dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(this, 0)
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), null)
    } else
        super.onDisplayPreferenceDialog(preference)
}
```

Comment: What exactly is showing as deprecated in that snippet?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() and the else statement

Comment: i don't know by what i should replace them

Comment: Are you sure the message is saying they're deprecated? What is the superclass of the class that your `onDisplayPreferenceDialog()` method is in?

Comment: it's in NumericPreference  but i removed it when I publishedthe code

Comment: Yeah, those aren't deprecated, then; they're just not resolvable there. That method belongs in a `PreferenceFragment` subclass, and you would use `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`. You might have another look at the example you're following.

Comment: Yeah i heard about the PreferenceFragment  but i have no idea how to implement it

Comment: Actually, it should be `PreferenceFragmentCompat`, these days, and the docs for that class have a [pretty decent example](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat#sample-code) for getting the basic setup going. Your `onDisplayPreferenceDialog()` method would go in the `PrefsFragment` class shown there, and then you would load that `PrefsFragment` into an `AppCompatActivity` just like you would any other `Fragment`.

Comment: yeah ... the class was already in my code but in the middle of something, that's way cleaner now

Comment: What should I do with dialogFragment.show()

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It's the same call, just with `getFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Uh ok after further reading of the documentation and wasting your time several times , i think i'v learned a lot , thank you Mike ^^ and know understand something about fragments